# I want to Autocomplete="off " but it doesn't work

Tags: jquery

I am using Autocomplete="off " but it doesn't work in my input field. code file share below please tell me where I'm wrong function file also share.

```
<input  type="text"id="return_address1_<?php echo $_GET['index'];?>" list="places" name=""  value="<?php echo isset($SEARCH['return_address']) ? pjSanitize::clean($SEARCH['return_address']) : NULL;?>" class="form-control pjTbsAddress" autocomplete="off" data-msg-required="<?php __('front_required_field');?>" required onchange="setTimeout(path_change, 3000);">
    <datalist id="places">
        <option value="Frankfurt Airport (FRA), frankfurt airport, Frankfurt am Main, Germany">
        <option value="FRA_HBF - Hauptbahnhof Frankfurt/Main">
        <option value="FMESSE_FFM - Messe Frankfurt am Main">
        <option value="Mainz, Germany">
    </datalist>
    function bindSearch(){  
        if(pjQ.$('#return_address1_' + self.opts.index).length > 0)
        {   
        var return_field = document.getElementById('return_address1_' + self.opts.index);
        var autocomplete_return = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(return_field, {
        types: ["geocode"]
        });
        google.maps.event.addDomListener(return_field, 'keydown', function(e) { 
        if (e.keyCode == 13) { 
        e.preventDefault(); 
        }
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete_return, 'place_changed', function() {
        self.calcRoute.call(self);
        });
        }
    }
```

Comment: What do you mean by "it doesn't work"? What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck?

Comment: If you are using chrome then you might have to use `autocomplete="nope"`

Comment: I think if you dont specifically set autocomplete, it wont... Just remove it i guess...

Comment: Nico Hasse I make a data list when I select any options Autocomplete Event trigger that why it shows suggestion. I am using Automcomplete="off" and other options like "nope", "disable" and "false" but it does not work

Comment: Carsten Løvbo Andersen, I make a data list when I select any options Autocomplete Event trigger that why it shows suggestion. I am using Automcomplete="off" and other options like "nope", "disable" and "false" but it does not work

Comment: Please add **all** clarification to your question by editing it